# How to remove a single item from the Recent Items menu in new OS X El Capitan?

Tags: macos, mac, system-preferences

I have been trying to find a solution on how to remove a single item from the Recent Items menu. Before upgrading to El Capitan everything worked just fine. I had downloaded Pref Setter software by Night Productions and used that to edit the /YOURUSERNAME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist. After the update, I no longer can find this file in the Preferences folder which is probably why Pref Setter no longer works.

I would really appreciate it if someone can help me figure this out. I have looked extensively online but have not come across a solution that works.

Thanks!

Comment: I have that file, though it's not been changed since Nov 7 & contains nothing of note, except 2 keys `MyFirstPrivateOverlay` & `OwnAreaDarwinLoopback` - extrapolation would be that it's no longer in use, or not in the same way

Answer (score 0):

I don't have this file on a clean install of El Capitan, which would appear to confirm the finding that it's no longer used.

This has changed in El Cap, per http://www.alfredforum.com/topic/8122-use-alfred-to-observe-contents-of-all-my-files/

> Pre-El Capitan, there was a plist file at "~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.recentitems.plist" containing the data you're after.
>
> In El Capitan, you can get the list of paths with the shell command:

```
mdfind -onlyin $HOME '((kMDItemContentModificationDate > $time.now(-60m)) && (kMDItemContentModificationDate < $time.now()))' | grep -v /Library/
```

> (This excludes files in "~/Library".)